# How would this sentence be properly formatted?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

"He expressed genuine interest in how both of our paths came to cross this day: me, a hundred miles from home, and him, only a moment away from leaving the locked entry."

Comment: What is the cause of your concern?

Comment: Not sure if the colon or formatting is proper at all.

Comment: I would favor an M-dash, but it's largely personal preference.

Comment: Both of our paths crossed—or only one of our paths crossed?

Comment: Yes; _how our paths crossed_ is sufficient. No need to count.